# What's wrong of the way to import react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I encounter the import error recently. 
If I import react via `import React from 'react'`, vscode hints error(picture below), but `import * as React from 'react'` can fix this error, I guess there is something wrong with my babel config, what's the problem?

Below is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.9.13",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.4",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.5",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    // other dependencies...
  }
}
```

[image: wrong]

[image: correct]

Comment: This eslint error will go away as soon as you make a react component and write some jsx.

Comment: Just create a component and then check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `tsconfig.json` file, inside compiler options, set `esModuleInterop` to `true`.

```
 {
   "compilerOptions": {
      "esModuleInterop": true,
```

Then you will be able to properly import it without TS warnings.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error stating that you have imported React in React placeholder but never used it, this can be treated as mere warning. Whenever you start using this placeholder the warning will go away.

Comment: It's not the main case in the question. The second warning will remain.